# Type with computed property using 'in' from type

Tags: typescript, types, computed-properties

I generate a Type `Option` from object `Options` using `typeof` and `keyof`.

I define another type - `Dropdown` which have computed property and use the `Option` using `in`.

I get an error:

> Property 'options2' is missing in type '{ [Options.option1]: string; }'.

How should I implement it right?

```ts
const Options = {
  option1: 'option1' as 'options1',
  option2: 'option1' as 'options2',
  option3: 'option1' as 'options3',
}

type Option = typeof Options[keyof typeof Options];
type Dropdown = { [key in Option]: string };

const obj: Dropdown = {
  [Options.option1]: 'test'
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20Options%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20option1%3A%20'option1'%20as%20'options1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20option2%3A%20'option1'%20as%20'options2'%2C%0D%0A%20%20option3%3A%20'option1'%20as%20'options3'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Option%20%3D%20typeof%20Options%5Bkeyof%20typeof%20Options%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Dropdown%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20Option%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%3A%20Dropdown%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BOptions.option1%5D%3A%20'test'%0D%0A%7D%20)

Comment: The goal is for the properties in `Dropdown` to be optional ? Because if so you are just missing a `?`: `{ [key in Option]?: string }`

Comment: Well, shame on me :) You are right. Thanks! If you wish, post it as answer so it will maybe help to other clumsy people..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I just needed to set the prop optional (`?`), like this:

```ts
const Options = {
  option1: 'option1' as 'options1',
  option2: 'option1' as 'options2',
  option3: 'option1' as 'options3',
}

type Option = typeof Options[keyof typeof Options];
type Dropdown = { [key in Option]?: string };

const obj: Dropdown = {
  [Options.option1]: 'test'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20Options%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20option1%3A%20'option1'%20as%20'options1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20option2%3A%20'option1'%20as%20'options2'%2C%0D%0A%20%20option3%3A%20'option1'%20as%20'options3'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Option%20%3D%20typeof%20Options%5Bkeyof%20typeof%20Options%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Dropdown%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20Option%5D%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%3A%20Dropdown%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BOptions.option1%5D%3A%20'test'%0D%0A%7D%20)